# Redirecting /index.php?country=a to /a/ by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, clean-urls

To redirect

```
www.example.com/index.php?country=a
```

to

```
www.example.com/a/
```

tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} index.php?country=a [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php?country=a
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/a/? [L,R=301]
```

Not works.

Notes:

1) This code is also a bad idea if `a` to be dynamic (60 countries in my list).

2) Anything after `index.php?country=a` e.g: `index.php?country=a&p=d&xx=k` to be removed.

Comment: Do you maybe want to do the opposite redirection? Why would you redirect "standard" url type to SEO type?

Comment: Probably you missing my second note. I'm not looking for clean URLs. Trying to delete bunch of disabled URLs.

Comment: You could also just do this in the PHP application. Instead of returning the (old) page, just return a `header('Location: http://example.com/country');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable  `%{QUERY_STRING}` represents the query part (the part after the ?) of an url,

so You can not match the uri   `index.php` in the pattern, try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^country=([^&]+)(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

Or

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?country=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

Clear your browser's cache before testing these rules.

Comment: So any way to match 'index.php'?

Comment: see the 2nd solution

Comment: Thanks but did you look the notes in question? 'a' is dynamic here

Comment: @smith Yes, i did!  do you want to redirect the incomming url of the form **/index.php?country=foo** to **/foo/** ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z]+) index.php?country=$1 [NC,L]
```

It will help you to to have a clean URL from any value, not only 'a'

Comment: it also ignore other values after country

Comment: Any rewrite condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^a$ index.php?country=a [NC,L]
```

this one for sure works... Make sure the index.php?country=a is not in any sub-directory